# Globalization in Razor view doesn't work asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

I've read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1 and added everything needed. Added needing in `Configure` and `ConfigureServices`.

This is my Startup methods:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContextPool<IDbContext, AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddScoped<ITaskBL, TaskBL>();
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            
            var supportedCultures = new[] { "en", "ru" };
            var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[1])
                .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
                .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
            
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

[This is my Resources hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kpqs.png)

Index.ru.resx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<root>
    <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
            
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    <resheader name="resmimetype">
        <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="version">
        <value>1.3</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <data name="Create task" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Создать задачу</value>
    </data>
    <data name="Create subtask" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Создать подзадачу</value>
    </data>
    <data name="Delete task" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Удалить задачу</value>
    </data>
</root>
```

And this is how I used it in view:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer _localizer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>@_localizer["Create task"]</p>
</div>
```

It renders `Create task`, which I think is the key value. Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `RootNamespace` element set in `.csproj`, by removing the element, I removed the issue.